# Finished basement. Is is possible to replace the plumbing when replacing the floor for the main level?

Tags: plumbing

Here is the context:
-this is a raised floor bungalow
-planing to do a full reno for two bathrooms (basement and ground level)
-finished basement
-downstairs the kitchen is adjacent to the bathroom (the ground level bathroom is just above the downstairs one)

I also have plans to replace the old hard floor for the ground level. I am just wondering ..is it possible to replace the plumbing (I need more pressure on both floors) by accessing it from above? I do understand that I will have a couple of vertical runs that I still have to deal with but since I am redoing the floor is is possible to open up from above to replace the long horizontal runs ?

Comment: we have no idea what your house looks like and how the plumbing is run .... it is up to you or up to a plumber to answer the questions

Comment: I am asking in principle if this is in general possible. As I said I expect he plumbing to be accessible from above as well especially the long runs

Comment: As @jsotola suggested, with the question as written the answer will be a definite "maybe." Adding more information, or even better a diagram, would help a lot.

Comment: i mean no offense, but it makes no sense why you are asking the question .... you can either work on the pipes from above, or you cannot ..... you are the only one who can determine that ..... the only thing that would make sense is if you are leaving out an important piece of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing specifics of how your plumbing is laid out or what you're wanting to do, it's tough to give a completely precise answer. That said, in general, you *can* access the plumbing if the floor is open - floor joists are up to ~12" tall, with pipes run through the middle, so they are well within the reach from the bathroom itself. With that same disclaimer, you're really only going to be able to make small-ish adjustments, as you won't have a whole lot of room to move pipes and drains across the room. Whether you will have enough access to do what you need to do will depend on the layout and your plans, and you will need to work with your plumber (or a tape measure!) to see what's possible.

If the horizontal runs are between (parallel to) joists, you'll have a much easier time replacing them than if they are run perpendicular to the joists.

There was an episode of [Holmes on Homes](https://makeitright.ca/tv-shows/holmes-on-homes/) where they renovated a bathroom in a similar situation (didn't want to or couldn't get access from below), and wound up rerunning some plumbing from above when they had the floor open (they also sistered some joists together to fix joists damaged from incorrectly run plumbing). I don't remember the name of the episode though, so can't provide a link / video showing the work, but it shows that it is possible, at least in some situations.

Comment: I did not expect a very precise answer but I wanted to know if there are any foreseeable obstacles that I am missing
Since I am removing the hardfloor for the entire main floor and since the floor is screeching a lot when I walk on it I guess I will either have to replace the plywood that is under the floor or screw it properly for the entire floor. So that being said I will have access for most of the areas where the pipes are run under. 

Thanks for the tip with Holmes on Homes, I will have a look to see if I can find that episode